# Connected Reinhardt Domain which is not complete

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Can i have an example of connected [Reinhardt domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhardt_domain) in $C^n$ which contains zero.  But it is not complete.

Complete means: For $w= (w_1,..w_n)\in D$, if $z$ is such that $|z_j|\leq |w_j$ for all $j$ implies $z\in D$.

Comment: $\{(z_1,\ldots,z_n) \mid |z_i| < 1 \} \cup \{(z_1,\ldots,z_n) \mid 2 < |z_i| < 3 \}$ would be an example

Comment: Sorry but i cant see: is this connected??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like $\{ (z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : |z| < 1, |w| < 1 \} \setminus \{ (z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 :  1/3 \le |z| \le 2/3, |w| \le 1/2 \}$ would work. Draw a picture in the $(|z|, |w|)$-plane to see what it looks like.

Comment: I think: $(0,0)\in \mathbb C^2$ doesn't lie in this.

Comment: How so? The origin certainly is inside the bidisc (the first set) and is not inside the piece that is removed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry my mistake.. thanks

Comment: You might consider upvoting as well as accepting the answer. I don't think the downvote was warranted.

Comment: I tried, but i can't upvote..Please edit something[even you can change fullstop and and bracket at the last] in the  answer, then upvote will be allowed for me... Thnx.